# Babaganoush SDK - which version of Sitefinity supported?

Tags: sitefinity

Babaganoush SDK - which version of Sitefinity supported?

-- error when used in Sitefinity version - 7.0.5115.0.

Does Babaganoush supports only - 7.0.5100

Comment: As far as I know it only supports the 7.0 official release.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an assembly binding for all of the 7.0.5100 assemblies babaganoush is referencing. For example:

`<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Sitefinity" publicKeyToken="b28c218413bdf563" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="7.1.5115.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>`